# como recibir un parametro de una funcion C++ en lenguaje ensamblador

Tags: c++, ensamblador

si yo tengo una función **IsValid(int a, int b, int c)**, pero en lenguaje ensamblador, como hago que reciba los parámetros para poder manipularlos desde el lenguaje ensamblador?

Ej.

```
extern "C" bool IsValidAssembly(int a, int b,int c);


.386
.model flat, C

.code

IsValidAssembly PROC

cmp a,b
jz son_iguales
jmp no_iguales

son_iguales:
mov c,a
jmp fin

no_iguales:
movc,b

fin:

IsValidAssembly ENDP
END
```

Comment: Pretendes usar ensamblador dentro de una función C++ o invocar una función ensamblador desde C++? no es lo mismo

Comment: invocarla desde un fichero externo

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar... código ensamblador embebido en código C++ o una función ensamblador llamada desde C++? El archivo en el que se encuentre cada código es irrelevante

Comment: Tampoco estaría de más añadir un ejemplo que muestre qué es lo que pretendes

Comment: ah perdon xD, embebido en C++

Comment: Y un ejemplo acerca de lo que pretendes hacer?

Comment: modifique la pregunta con un ejemplo de comparar dos valores

Comment: Son deberes de clase? Si no no se me ocurre para qué vas a usar ensamblador en estos supuestos

Comment: es para un trabajo, el caso es mas complejo , pero puse eso como un ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con algo así:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>

extern int suma(int, int, int) __asm__("suma");

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::cout << suma(1, 2, 3);

  return 0;
}
```

Siendo el contenido de `test.h` el siguiente:

```
asm(
"\n.intel_syntax noprefix"
"\n.globl suma"
"\nsuma:"
"\n    add     edi, esi"
"\n    lea     eax, [rdi+rdx]"
"\n    ret"
"\n.att_syntax prefix"
);
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OSW00N4EmmjJMIve)